Increasing voltage from 5 V VCC (i.e. logic HIGH) to 12 V during operation
I'm working with a handful of NOR flash chips that have a write protection mechanism where the memory can't be written to unless the blocks are unprotected. Evidently, unprotecting them requires the HIGH-level logic voltage on the RESET (RP#) pin to transition from 5 V (VIH) to around 12 V (the so-called identification voltage, or VID) over a minimum rise-time of 500ns (see the images below).
I did try a naïve approach of using a voltage divider a-la breadboard & hand-operated pot, but it seems the IC sinks too much current, preventing the desired voltages being presented on the pin.
Frankly, I just don't have the knowledge or experience in this area. What kind of circuit can be used to--at runtime--increase the voltage to an IC's pin from 5 V to 12 V over some known period of time? The output current would need to be very low (lest the magic smoke be released from the IC).
I'm aware of charge pumps and boost converters, but as far as I can tell these can't change their output voltage on-demand. But, it's quite possible I'm wrong about that.
Of course, I can just buy a programmer on AliExpress, but I won't learn anything from that.
The following images are from the Micron M29FxxxFT/B datasheet:




Have you confirmed that the blocks are actually protected? I think devices from the factory don't have any blocks protected, albeit the datasheet doesn't seem to explicitly state that. From the datasheet you should be able to issue a AUTO SELECT Command and then the block protection status of individual blocks. Where the AUTO SELECT and reading of the block protection status don't appear to need VID applied to any pin. How are the M29FxxxFT/B flash chips connected to a device, and are you able to write code to issue the AUTO SELECT command and read the block protection status?

@ChesterGillon I expected the chips to be unprotected too, but the polling and toggle bits do not behave as the datasheet says they should in response to the program and other commands. It does say that if the block you’re trying to write to is protected, then it will ignore the commands and the status will not be set. The datasheet is confusing. On first read it seems like the auto select command should work without VID, but text that appears later in the document does suggest it’s required. Regardless, I did try the auto select command as well, but the result was the same: nothing.

The chips are soldered to prototype boards and I’m interfacing with them using an arduino mega - for the time being. I have other similar chips that do not have the protection feature, and I am able to program those fine.

It's not hard to change the output voltage of a dc-dc converter. You'd just have to design in a switchable feedback network.

You would use a charge pump or boost converter to generate the +12V, and then a separate transistor switch to apply the necessary waveform to the pin.
To control a high-side switch from a low-level logic signal, you'll need two transistors. Here's one way to do it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
And most charge pumps and boost converters do normally have an enable pin that can be used to start and stop them, but it may not produce the rise/fall times that you need, so you'll still need the separate switch.

Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate on how the transistor switch would produce the required rise time?
